# Is there any way to mine using an integrated GPU?

Tags: gpu-mining, mining-hardware

Is it possible to mine with an AMD APU's integrated GPU, or Intel's integrated graphics processors? If so, any idea what kind of hashrate one can get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wolf's GPU miner works with AMD integrated GPUs too. I tested it several months ago. https://twitter.com/hyc_symas/status/695730032291917825

On the A10-4600M each CPU thread got about 50H/s. In my laptop, the dGPU gets about 90H/s. The iGPU gets around 40H/s. These numbers are from memory and I may be misremembering.

With the current AMD driver on Linux, you can only have one GPU active at a time, so you can't enable one for driving the display and use the other for number crunching. It's quite inconvenient. (The open source driver lets you run both GPUs at once, but it lacks support for OpenCL 2.0.)

Correction: not sure if due to an update, but the current AMD driver now allows both GPUs to be active at once. (2016-10-14)

I've just tested with 2 out of 4 CPU threads, plus both the dGPU and iGPU active at the same time. Overall hash rate is slower than just using the CPU + dGPU without the iGPU. This is because the iGPU competes with the CPU for RAM access. With just 2 CPU threads and dGPU, the dGPU gets 89.5H/s and the CPU threads get 50H/s each. Adding the iGPU to the mix, the iGPU gets only 13H/s, the dGPU drops to 87.5H/s, and the CPU threads drop to 23.6H/s.

This is in an Asus N56DP laptop with A10-4600M APU and Radeon HD 7730M dGPU.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize it was supported. I guess the same is true about the AMD driver for Windows, or enabling an nvidia driver and having Intel or AMD integrated graphics activated?

Comment: No idea about those other scenarios, sorry.